# Using doctrine translatable together with Symfony 2 forms

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have Entity in my app, which has 2 translatable fields, using Doctrine Translatable Extension:

```
class Page implements Translatable
{
    /......

    /**
     * @var string $name
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var text $content
     * @Gedmo\Translatable  
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content; 

 /........
}
```

I use one table for multiple entities translations.
Now i would like to use **one** form to get the original and translated (to 1 language) values for these attributes, so it should have 4 fields.

I've defined new form derivating from AbstractType and tried to add those 2 fields using FormBuilder, but it says that their corresponding entities do not contain these fields. I've tried to add these fields to entities, and declare getters for them, but the only way i know to get translations for entities is to use dedicated entity manager and AFAIK providing entity manager access to entity isn't good practice.

Is there a way to use forms to handle such thing?

Comment: it don't know if it fits your needs but this bundle worked great for me https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle

Comment: Your can use TranslationExtraBundle: https://github.com/ideea/TranslationExtraBundle
And open source project, when use this bundle: https://github.com/ZhukV/Nadiyka

Comment: Please post your code from the FormType.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but anyway.

You could put the fields for translated content using FormBuilder with attribute:

`array('mapped'=>false)`

Take the data like this:

```
$form->get('field_name')->getData();
```

and then persist it like this

https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#multi-translations

I hope it helps somebody.